# Java Crashed application - how to read crash file generated by JVM?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, crash, jvm

I have java aplication and it started to crash sudently, without no exception. But sometimes JVM creates crash log file, which has name like: "hs_err_pid10930.log". Can anybody read it and tell me what is wrong? I am not able to find out what si wrong.  The only reasonable info which I find here is that swap size is 0.  I that a problem? How could it occure?

You can find the file here: http://chessfriends-release.s3.amazonaws.com/logs/hs_err_pid10930.log?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJP5BYGKOCMCDVZHA&Expires=1305128715&Signature=XEZMuJ0xNSM6YTcdwsI04ahhiYk%3D

Thanks.

Libor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you get a crash like this it's almost never the Java programmer's fault because the JVM is crashing which it shouldn't.  By looking at your log file, it looks like it's crashing somewhere in the OpenJDK's JVM; I don't know what specifically is causing it.  I would suggest you try out Oracle's official JDK rather than OpenJDK.

I'm not an expert on reading these sorts of crash dumps, but this is the part I use to identify what is causing the problem:

```
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x64d62d]
```

This is at the top of the dump.  It's not always libjvm.so; I've seen some with like libGL.so.

If you would like to file a bug, the dump includes this statement:

```
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-6/
```

I don't know what it is you're doing that causes the crash, and maybe there is a workaround.  But under no circumstances should the JVM crash, so this is a bug in the JVM you're using.

**Edit**
The log says you're running Ubuntu 9.10; there have been two Ubuntu releases since then so I doubt filing a bug would do any good unless you test this out on either Ubuntu 10.04 or 10.10.  I don't know if you're able to upgrade to a newer version, but your problem may have already been fixed.

Comment: looking a few lines down in the hs_err stacktrace, the crash comes from code invoked by `org.mortbay.io.nio.ChannelEndPoint.flush(org.mortbay.io.Buffer)` and `org.mortbay.jetty.HttpGenerator.flush()`